# Is there something like npm scripts for elm-package.json?

Tags: elm, package.json

I use `npm scripts` a lot for my javascript/node projects (`npm start`, `npm test`, and `npm run build` and others), and I was wondering if there is something similar for elm-packages, or if we should use `npm scripts` instead, and if I have to do it, why do we need a `package.json` and a `elm-package.json`?

Comment: Might be more helpful to say what you want to achieve, and we can advise on how Elm devs currently do that?

Comment: I want to run small tasks as I do with npm scripts but without having a package.json

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is that (as of May 2017) there's **not** support for this in `elm-package.json`.

As for the future: Evan Czaplicki [has said](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/elm-dev/elm-package.json%7Csort:relevance/elm-dev/qdu3NqOqGrY/_jRl5ROiBAAJ) on elm-dev mailing list that the file format and functionality will get revamped a little bit (probably with the 0.19 release), but most probably mainly with regards to application vs. library distinction. **Based on that, I don't think `elm-package.json` will get this functionality anytime soon.**

Answer (score 1):

I think most devs have some node stuff running to handle their dev environment (e.g. webpack stuff) so you will always have package.json available for such scripts anyway.

There is a question about whether elm should embed its dependencies within package.json but, while *most* dev instances would have package.json, anyone just trying out with elm-reactor would not. So I think the present situation is here to stay, and enables you to do what you want.